# Use BeautifulSoup to get texts without a tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get some text without tags using BeautifulSoup. I tried using *.string*, *.contents*, *.text*, *.find(text=True)*, and *.next_sibling*, and they are listed below.

**Edit**
Nvmd I just noticed that *.next_sibling* works for me. Anyways this question can be a note collecting methods handling similar case.

```
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup
s = """
<p>
    <a>
        Something I can fetch but don't want
    </a> 
    I want to fetch this line.
    <a>
        Something else I can fetch but don't want
    </a>
</p>
"""

p = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
print p.contents            
    # [u'\n', <p>
    # <a>
    #     Something
    # </a> 
    #     I want to fetch this line.
    # <a>
    #     Something else
    # </a>
    # </p>, u'\n']

print p.next_sibling.string 
    # I want to fetch this line.
print p.string              
    # None
print p.text        
    # all the texts, including those I can get but don't want.
print p.find(text=True)
    # Returns an empty line of type bs4.element.NavigableString
print p.find(text=True)[0]
    # Returns an empty line of type unicode
```

I'm wondering if there is a simpler method than manually parsing the string s to get the line I want to fetch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It is still rough but at least it doesn't require you to manually parse the strings.

```
#get all non-empty strings from the backend.
texts = [str.strip(x) for x in p.strings if str.strip(x) != '']

#get strings only with tags
unwanted_text = [str.strip(x.text) for x in p.find_all()]

#take the difference
set(texts).difference(unwanted_text)
```

This yields:

```
In [87]: set(texts).difference(unwanted_text)
Out[87]: {'I want to fetch this line.'}
```